# What does G mean, as on the DRG button on a calculator?

Tags: geometry

I saw the superscript "g" in my calculator under the DRG (degrees, radian,...) function and i am curious as to what it actually means.
Thanks Everyone

Comment: not clear what you're asking, but [gradian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) is a unit of measurement of angles, $100$ grad$ = 90^o$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[Gradian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) is a unit of measurement of angles.

$100$ grad$=90^o=\dfrac\pi2$ radians.

Answer (score 1):

Gradians is a unit of measure of angles introduced in the first version of metric system around $1795$ by french scientists. As said by @J. W. Tanner, it is based on a natural unit, the right angle, a quarter of a full angle, which is divided into 100 parts, just like the meter has been at first defined as $\frac{1}{10 000 000}$ of the quarter of another natural unit, the length of the equator.

Whereas the meter has become (under different successive definitions, no longer connected to the Earth) the unit of length used almost everywhere, the gradian has been progressively abandonned : degree (coming from babylonians) are still used almost universaly, competing in science with radians.

The main drawback of gradians is that the so-important angles that are a third and two-thirds of a right angle (in degrees : 30° and 60°, in radians $\pi/6$ and $\pi/3$) are resp. $33.33...$ and $66.66...$ gradians. Not that practical...

Comment: Did you mean @J.W. *Tanner*?

Comment: Why Wells ? I don't know... Sorry for completely misnaming you. I fix it now.